# Autocomplete brackets in methods | Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have to type parentheses after methods manually. Where  can i find an option to do this task automatically?
i already look at edition > General > Code Completion in setting, but there isn't an option like that.

Best,
Sebastian.

Comment: Do you mean when you write the opening parenthesis, it doesn't auto-complete it with the closing one?

Comment: No, when i type the first letters of a fuction and the autocomplete shows the complete function and then i select and press enter, the function doesn't appear with both parenthesis.

Comment: For me, it autocompletes my methods, i.e.: I write list.a, shows a drop down menu, click tab and then it autocompletes to `list.append()`.